# Full screen video tearing in firefox Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: firefox, 19.04

When I play a video in fullscreen with firefox (i.e. youtube, netflix etc.) it tears constantly. Chrome, Chromium and Opera don't have this problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are certain the issue is with Firefox and it is not system wide then the following may solve your issue.

Type "about:config" (without quotes) in your address bar in firefox, click accept if prompted and then search for `layers.acceleration.force-enabled`. Double click the search result to turn the value to true.

Now restart firefox and the issue should be solved.

Comment: Thanks! but now why wouldn't watching netflix "enable" acceleration by default?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in 20.10, but `layers.acceleration.force-enabled = true` alone doesn't worked for me. Here is an approach that finally worked for me. https://askubuntu.com/a/1288650/975640